# Having Trouble with 2-Dimensional Array of Structs C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, struct

I have searched this website and Google, and haven't really found anything that solves my problem. I am trying to write a game right now, and this game contains a map of terrain tiles that the player can move across. I want to store the tiles in a 10x10 array, but I am having trouble initializing the array.

I can initialize the first dimension of the array, but the error lies within initializing the second dimension within the first for loop.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
//tile on the "map"
struct tile
{
    char type;
    bool isWall;
};

void initializeMap(tile * map)
{
  int index1, index2;

  for(index1 = 0; index1 < 10; index1++)
  {
    map[index1] = new tile[10];

    for(index2 = 0; index2 < 10; index2++)
    {

    }
  }
}

int main()
{
    tile * tileMap = new tile[10];
    initializeMap(tileMap);

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
C:\Users\----\Desktop\TextGame.cpp||In function 'void initializeMap(tile*)':|
C:\Users\----\Desktop\TextGame.cpp|39|error: no match for 'operator=' in '*(map + ((unsigned int)(((unsigned int)index1) * 2u))) = (tile*)operator new [](20u)'|
C:\Users\----\Desktop\TextGame.cpp|9|note: candidates are: tile& tile::operator=(const tile&)|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Comment: Wouldn't it need to be a `tile**` since you are packing `tile*` into map?

Comment: @zero298 Pretty sure thats the issue right there, clean it up a bit and post it as an answer

Comment: I recommend changing variable names, as `std::map` already exists and variable name of `map` may cause conflicts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to set an actual object to a pointer with the command:

`map[index1] = new tile[10];`

`map` is a `tile*`.  However, `map[index1]` is a deferenced `tile*` making it actually a `tile` which cannot equal a `tile*` which `new tile[10]` gives you.

Therefore, your code will work better as:

```
struct tile {
   char type;
   bool isWall;
};

/**
 * Initialize the map
 * @param map The array of tile pointers
 */
void initializeMap(tile** map) {
   int index1, index2;
   for (index1 = 0; index1 < 10; index1++) {

      // Set each element of the tile* array 
      // to another array of tile pointers
      map[index1] = new tile[10];

      for (index2 = 0; index2 < 10; index2++) {
         // Do Something
      }
   }
}

int main() {
   // Create a pointer to a set of tile pointers
   tile** tileMap = new tile*[10];
   // Pass it to the initializer
   initializeMap(tileMap);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes more sense. I was trying to make tileMap a double pointer when I first tried this but couldn't get the syntax right.

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** Technically, thats not a 2-dimensional array, is an array of arrays of structs.

Said that, that note reflects the problem of your code: You have an array of arrays, so the first allocation **should allocate an array which contents are pointers to other arrays**:

```
tile** tilemap = new tile*[10];

for( std::size_t i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i )
    tilemap[i] = new tile[10];

....

//Dealocation at program finish:

for( std::size_t i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i )
    delete tilemap[i];

delete tilemap;
```

However your code could be improved if you use standard containers, like `std::vector`, instead of manual memory management, which is error-prone:

```
std::vector<std::vector<tile>> tilemap( 10 );

for( std::size_t i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i )
    tilemap.emplace_back( 10 );
```

Comment: +1 for recommending against using memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a `std::vector` of shared pointers to tiles.  This will allow you to have different tiles and store them into the vector:

```
struct Tile; // As you declared it.

struct Water_Tile : public Tile;
struct Mountain_Tile : public Tile;
struct Desert_Tile : public Tile;

// ...
typedef std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<Tile> > Tile_Container;

//...
Tile_Container    my_world(10 * 10);

// ...
my_world[20] = new Water_Tile;
```

A nice advantage of the shared pointer is that it handles memory management (deletion) for you.

Comment: This is pretty interesting. The syntax looks a little intimidating as I have not really bothered learning about the std::vector yet. They can be resized on the fly though right?

Comment: The size of `std::vector` can be set at creation, or expanded as needed when using the `push_back` method.